# Silverlight input UTF letters in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: encoding, utf-8, localization, silverlight-3.0

I have a Silverlight 3 app with AutoCompleteBox for user to enter search phrase. Users has to be able to enter Lithuanian characters (UTF-8 encoding).
In code i set culture to `lt-LT`:
    `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(e.InitParams["lt-LT"]);
     Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(e.InitParams["lt-LT"]);`
Everything works perfectly in IE, Opera and Safari, but in Firefox and Chrome it is impossible to enter characters like `ąčęėįšųū`. Maybe somebody can help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I Found a solution for this problem. Problem was in asp.net page silverlight object declaration. The problem was solved by removing this tag:

```
<param name="Windowless" value="true" />
```